# PHP Add New Line to Array Values Inside One Row and Column in Database Table

Tags: php

I managed to add multiple data in one column in the database, but now I need to display it with a new line in the browser so they don't stick with each other as I display them as an array in one column.

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 5) {

            $subArray = array("StudentAnswer");
            $subId6 = $db->get("answertable", null, $subArray);

            foreach ($subId6 as $sub) {
                $answers[] = $sub['StudentAnswer'] . "\n";
            }

            foreach ($answers as $row) {
                $answers2 = explode("||", $row[0]);
        
                  foreach($answers2 as $row2){
                        $answers3 = $row2 . '\n';
                    }
            }

            $db->where('AccessId', $_GET['token']);
            $db->where('StudentAnswer', $answers3);
            $subId8 = $db->get("answertable");


            if ($subId8) {
                echo json_encode($subId8);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You are overwriting `$subId6` inside a loop that is processing `$subId6` Its a nighhtmare :)

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string of answers seperated by a space then simply do

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 5) {
            
    $subId6 = $db->get("answertable");
    foreach ($subId6 as $sub) {
        $answers .= $sub['StudentAnswer'] . ' ';
    }
    $answers= rtrim($answers, ' '); //remove last space in case thats an issue later

    $db->where('AccessId', $_GET['token']);
    $db->where('StudentAnswer', $answers);
    $subId8 = $db->get("answertable");

    if ($subId8) {
        echo json_encode($subId8);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want a newline at the end of each answer?

Comment: Yeah, that too. I needed to insert anything in those array values. Tried using implode to that it earlier but it doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure I understand, if you can explain what you want I can change the answer to work as you wish it to

Comment: Okay, I'll update my question. I just thought that your answer would still work if I'll only be putting something inside the array. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding `$subId6` after getting its content. Try to fetch the table `$rows` in a new variable and the extract the content from it, like the code below.

```
<?php
// Example of $subId6 content
$subId6 = array(["StudentAnswer" => ["Answer 1\nAnswer 2\nAnswer 3"]], ["StudentAnswer" => ["Answer 1\nAnswer 2\nAnswer 3"]]);

// Fetch rows
foreach ($subId6 as $sub) {
    $rows[] = $sub['StudentAnswer'];
}

// Decode rows
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $answers = explode("\n", $row[0]);
    
    echo "New answers: \n";
    
    // Split answers in single answer
    foreach ($answers as $answer)
        echo "$answer \n";
        
    echo "\n";
}
```

You will have a list of all the answers split for table rows

Comment: Nice answer. Although, I can't seem to replicate the answer. Thank you though, I'll be using using your code as a reference.

Comment: Also, instead of explode, I wanted to implode it with a new line. What I needed to explode was || because I used it as a separator for the array in my column. 
P.S. Yes, I did have something in the array, but that was for inserting, now I'm getting.